# How to use "LESS" in angularjs project using UI-ROUTER

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, less, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap template in my angularjs project which is served by Grunt. Everything else is working fine, but the Components of bootstrap template which are using LESS are not getting rendered on page when I use ui-router for routing.

How to do it while using ui-router?

Comment: Please provide some code sample using less, jsbin etc.

Comment: What type of code sample do you require?

Comment: when I am using template page in my index.html I am getting proper result. But when I am using `<div ui-view=""></div>` for routing purpose. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grunt-contrib-less` package to integrate less integration using Grunt. An example configuration could be:
1. Add the package via npm

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-less
```

2. Load the package in your gruntfile.js:

   `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');`
3. Add the config for less:

> 

```
less: {
  development: {
    options: {
      paths: ['assets/css']
    },
    files: {
      'path/to/result.css': 'path/to/source.less'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly will this do? Will this convert .less files into .css or something else?

Comment: Yes. It is use to compile less to css. For more reference check this: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less

Comment: My .less file is calling a opacity function **opacity()** which is defined in another file. How should I use this?

Comment: I am getting output for normal html page. But when I am using ui-router CSS is not showing up.